# set -D macro compiler flag globally for libclang

Tags: c++, c, macros, clang, libclang

I am trying to generate mutants for a code (with an AST based mutant generator) which in order to compile uses -D macros. I am able to use clang to generate an AST dump using this command

> clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only -DFLAG=0 -DOTHER_FLAG file.c

But, the mutant generator tool (Milu) uses libclang to parse the c code and generate the AST. Without these macros, libclang is not able to parse the code properly, and it's not possible to add the #defines in the code. I want to set these -D macros globally.

For example, I can set an environment variable C_INCLUDE_PATH which is read by libclang. I am wondering if I can do something similar for -D macros.

Comment: You will need to pass those in to your compiler instance in some way. There is no environment variables for "defines", only lbraries and include locations.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a global configuration file for clang as well like _configure.ac_ for gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass them when creating your `CXTranslationUnit`. The [relevant function `clang_createTranslationUnit`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__TRANSLATION__UNIT.html#gaf45dfbcd2e4d8e9eeab4778f994a74c3) takes arguments similar to `argv` and `argc`.